# Cannot perform this action after onsaveinstancestate after using liveData for fragments transition

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-livedata

this one question has been bothering me for 6 months, it is like a missing peace.. So, I really like LiveData and use it a lot, perhaps too much. Basically, all our fragments adding and removing is managed **by LiveData**. I have done it for several reasons:

1. We need to remove fragments in some cases, after onPause has occurred (odd, but a must for our use case).
2. We have only a single activity with fragments.

I have created a specific navigationViewModel which is shared across all fragments and is created in activity.

I add, remove fragments in this manner:

```
//ViewModel
...
 val addFragmentNr3 = SingleLiveEvent<Boolean>()

//Activity or some fragment calls this:
 navigationViewModel.addFragmentNr3.value = true
```

Then I observe LiveData in Activity and handling transition:

​

```
navigationViewModel.addFragmentNr3.observe(this, Observer { response ->
            if (response != null) {
                if (response) {
                    router.addFragmentNr3(supportFragmentManager)
                }
            }
        })
```

Then router handles it:

```
 fun addFragmentNr3(supportFragmentManager: FragmentManager) {
            val fragmentNr3 = FragmentNr3()
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.root_layout, fragmentNr3, FRAGMENT_NR_3.commit()}
```

In my honest opinion this **should definitely prevent** from this crash:java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

However, it does occur in our crash analytics.. It occurs rarely after more complex logic (*like updating livedata after onActivityResult),* but it does occur...

My main question is: Isn't it is a case, that LiveData handles such scenarios and would emit results only when it safe to perform operations? If not, it means my **logic is bad and this approach is complete failure.**

P.S. I would like to use navigation library, but as I said we have to *manually remove some fragments after user goes to background, or uses split mode and etc.*

Answer (score 1):

`LiveData` does not know whether an action is safe to perform or not.

<del>`onSaveInstanceState()` is called sometime before `onStop()` for Android version below P. So there is a small chance that the observer gets notified *after* `onSaveInstanceState()` is called.</del>

According to [doc](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle#onStop-and-savedState), it turned out that `onSaveInstanceState()` should mark the lifecycle as `CREATED` and observers are not supposed to be called after `onSaveInstanceState()`.

Suggestion on how to fix it.

One way is to use [Android Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-getting-started) component and let it handle all of the fragment transaction.

If this is not feasible--like op's case--I suggests just using `.commitAllowingStateLoss()`.

```
 fun addFragmentNr3(supportFragmentManager: FragmentManager) {
            val fragmentNr3 = FragmentNr3()
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.root_layout, fragmentNr3, FRAGMENT_NR_3
                .commitAllowingStateLoss()}
```

Now, if you search on the internet there will be dozens of articles warning how using `.commitAllowingStateLoss()` is bad. I believe these claims are no longer applicable to modern Android development where view restoration does not rely on saved bundles. If you are building an Android application with view models, you hardly need to rely on the Android framework to do the saving. In a proper MVVM application, the view should be designed in a way that it can restore its complete state based on its view models, and view models only.

Comment: Wow, really thank you for quality answer, so rare these days! :) Can you suggest some good way to prevent this crash?I saw various examples of preventing this exception, like ensuring that you add executePendingTransactions() after commit()... Like you said it does happen only rarely and as some logs show, on many old devices...

Comment: Can you explain a little more about this:
"In a proper MVVM application, the view should be designed in a way that it can restore its complete state based on its view models, and view models only."

we could discuss this in a chat, if you have some time :) It does not work well in our case...

Comment: @Viktor, yes we can. Please open a chat and share what didn't work well for your project.